# how to maintain whitespace wrap on css-transform scale operation

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

When I clone my

```
<div id="orig" class="content">this is just some content</div>
```

and append it into a smaller fixed size container, making it fit using css

```
#clone {
    transform: translate(...) scale(...)
}
```

then this messes with the original white-space wrap, even though the scale makes the element fit perfectly given the original whitespace wrap.

I know why that happens, but I need to find a way to avoid it.

In other words:

Given the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JAS2K/5/

I need the red `#badwrap1` to look like the below grey `#desiredwrap` (i.e with identical whitespace wrap), even though it's a child of a fixed size container.

Comment: Any fiddle or your sample code about #clone

Answer (score 0):

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/JAS2K/7/)

Changed your DOM and CSS a bit and it's working.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container1" class="content scaled">
    this is just some content
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.content {
    background-color:#DDD;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    min-height:40px;
}
#container1 {
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:red;
}
.scaled {
    -webkit-transform:translate(-25%, 0) scale(0.5, 1);
    transform: translate(-25%, 0) scale(0.5, 1);
}
```

Comment: I've simplified the question. I need to define a different fixed width per #containerN. And I need to group them side-by-side, avoiding whitespace. This problem is illustrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/JAS2K/8/
Because of this I believe I need the fixed size parent container.

Comment: A fixed size container (1 per scaled) is out of question, correct? I need to think about this a bit. It could do. I'm not sure if I can address the following concerns: 1. decorate scaled elements with non-scaled button, avoiding inverse scaling because there's one interaction where the box goes to normal size and back. 2. making the reds sortable (I assume I'd have to write this func from scratch).

Comment: and my final css width is in %. I put px here so the wrap is well-defined.

Comment: I can't understand. Do you want it to be fixed?

Comment: The whitespace wrap position should not be fixed but should be identical to what happens to #orig, and #orig has a size in %. Currently I'm solving it by placing another 100% div (size relative to #orig) which is mostly overflow-hidden, and doing the scale there. But I'm dearly missing a non-scaling containing elmt for each copy that makes decoration, moves etc. so much easier.

Comment: and fixed px size copies is ok, but just to note that the #orig width/height is in %. hope that answers